# I get a bash syntax error message every time I open Terminal on macbook

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, bash

```
-bash: /Users/admin/.bash_sessions/720116FC-4C25-4FFA-AC15-00D5C843C15F.session: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ('
-bash: /Users/admin/.bash_sessions/720116FC-4C25-4FFA-AC15-00D5C843C15F.session: line 1: echo Restored session:
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What command are you trying to execute?

Comment: His question title is 'I get a bash syntax error message *every time I open Terminal on macbook*'. I don't think he has any starting commands.

Answer (score 2):

Open /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal (requires sudo), replace

```
echo echo Restored session: $(date) >| "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE"
```

with

```
echo echo \"Restored session: $(date)\" >| "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE"
```

The point is to quote the echoed message.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by OS X bash session restoration process which inserts in every '.session' file command like this:

```
echo Restored session: суббота, 25 июня 2016 г. 23:29:08 (MSK)
```

We should not use symbols like '(' in echo command text without being wrapped in quotation marks, but OS X forgot about it, alas.
The only way for me to get rid of this naughty error message is to disable bash sessions at all:

```
touch ~/.bash_sessions_disable
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of bash's session files got corrupted.

```
rm  /Users/admin/.bash_sessions/*
```

should fix this.